# How can someone use bubbles to defeat a dragon?

Tags: dragons, balancing-magic-systems, tactics, strategy

6 mighty warriors from different places convened to discuss a plan to get rid of the evil fire-breathing dragon the size of a double decker.
The leader came from the Fire nation, had mastered the control of fire at the age of 4 months, and now at 22 had been released from jail for arson.
The genius from Water nation, nicknamed 'Waterboy' by his water polo team, had won his 3rd consecutive bronze at the Olympics.
The cool kid, exiled by the King of Ice nation for exposing the royal marital affair to the world, had his title for being the quickest ice cream eater removed.
The twins came from the Wind and Thunder nations. The brother could fly up to 10 kites during a thunderstorm, while the sister seemed to attract storms at random times.
The last member is from Bubble nation.

Their skills are as follows:

- The leader can shoot fireballs and will deliver the final blow to the dragon.
- Waterboy can control the humidity in the air to ensure the party is comfortable during the fight.
- The cool kid can spot the dragon's weakness and treat any burn injury using ice.
- The twins can distract the dragon to have it lose focus and also hopefully draw the dragon towards the cumulonimbus clouds.
- But **what good can someone who can blow bubbles do?**

Comment: [Reads title] > [imagines D&D players describing how they're blowing bubbles at a hostile dragon with kids bubble makers accompanied by some convoluted explanation of how this is supposed to defeat it or make it less hostile] > as a GM I'd laugh my socks off, the dragon would still eat them though ;)

Comment: If the bubbles are just ordinary soap bubbles you've nothing more than a distraction here, at best you've got a D&D wall of fog style effect if he can make enough of the things .. the soap or detergent element of enough soap bubbles might be useful against a few very specific things, Soaps will kill many insect pests, including aphids, mealybugs, whiteflies, spittlebugs and slugs etc, it's not got any great effect against what's basically a giant lizard that I'm aware of though.

Comment: "waterboy can control the humidity so the party is comfortable" - "what good can someone who can blow bubbles do". You just made the water-controlling boy a humidifier, and can't think of a way to humiliate another team member? hahah

Comment: If air is entrained into water, it loses buoyancy, and if they need to surface to breathe then they will suffocate. - You have Aquaman on land, trying to fight birds. Needs to be a sea dragon, otherwise, if your green friend won't be joining us.... - "can control the humidity in the air" - he has control over the weather and you're asking about bubbles? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Icing_conditions

Comment: Put enough bubbles together and you have foam. Foam can be used to estinguish fire.

Comment: You don't provide nearly enough information to provide a definitive answer.   What are these bubbles made of?  Where can they be created?  How?  Size?  Strength? etc.  Right now I can speculate that these are acid or poison bubbles, making the Bubble Nation the most deadly.  And if they are water bubbles, how are they different from the already undervalues and underpowers the water user.

Comment: "How do you use bubbles to defeat a dragon?"   Have you played Pokémon?  XD

Answer (score 14, accepted):

### Bubbleboy is the most deadly of them

Look at the Fantastic Four. There's the hulking Thing, clobbering everybody. There's "Flame On" Torch, burning down all the sofas. There's "Mr. Fantastic" bending and thinking. And then there's Susan, who can create bubbles of force. Who's the most deadly of them? That's a silly question. Of course, it's Susan.

But what does Susan, who makes forcefields and turns invisible, do that makes her so deadly? She's all defensive, right? **Dead wrong**. She can create her forcefields around heads and have the users choke to death. She can create her bubbles through bodies and create a bloody mess amputating body parts. She can trap enemies in bubbles of pure force and then throw them far far away!

Bubbleboy is just like Susan: all that saves him from curb stomping and killing all the other members of the team and going for world domination is that Bubbleboy is a calm and gentle person who hates shedding blood. It takes him going all *Mama Bear* on an enemy to turn them into a bloody mess. **Don't** get on Bubbleboy's bad side, or it will take all the other team members to rein him in from ending you in the most gruesome way he can imagine, such as happened in [Fantastic Four #549](https://www.reddit.com/r/marvelcomics/comments/xlz3le/do_not_mess_with_the_invisible_woman_fantastic/).

Comment: Although a great answer on all accounts, I think the question @joachim is asking is more about soap bubbles? I see no force field related things in the post.

Comment: I mean @user6760. My bad.

Comment: https://www.smbc-comics.com/comic/2006-06-08

Answer (score 9):

**Bubble Boy can incapacitate the flaming breath of the dragon.**

You know, breathing bubbles is not fun.
Since the dragon must take a deep breath in order to ingest enough air to spit a powerful flame, addressing a powerful stream of bubbles against its nose and mouth would force it to take smaller breaths, so that its flaming power would be severely hampered.

Reducing this way the main threat from the dragon, the rest of the team would have an easier job defeating it.

Bubble boy could also launch bubbles and have Cool kid freezing them. This would allow to create protective walls or even stairways that allow the team to have a better fight against a flying creature. Or, if the frozen bubbles are not strong enough, they could still work as decoy or as a way to confuse the enemy.

Answer (score 5):

If the bubbles can be filled with a narcotic or toxic gas, they can be used to bring a usable dose of narcotic in close proximity of the dragon, sending it to sleep or killing it without affecting the entire country when spraying the same molecule from a distance and having it naturally diffuse in the atmosphere.

Even better, if the bubbles can be made with low visibility, or are not visible to the dragon, they can deliver a stealth threat.

Answer (score 5):

It all depends on how these bubbles are formed.

Is the bubbly hero shooting out those bubbles out of their own body, or forming them externally?

Because if it's the latter, you've got the most OP assassin ever in your team due to

## [Air Embolism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Air_embolism)

> An air embolism, also known as a gas embolism, is a blood vessel blockage caused by one or more bubbles of air or other gas in the circulatory system.
>
> Symptoms of arterial gas embolism [note: in divers] include:
>
> - Loss of consciousness
> - Cessation of breathing
> - Vertigo
> - Convulsions
> - Tremors
> - Loss of coordination
> - Loss of control of bodily functions
> - Numbness
> - Paralysis
> - Extreme fatigue
> - Weakness in the extremities
> - Areas of abnormal sensation
> - Visual abnormalities
> - Cognitive impairment
> - Nausea or vomiting
> - Bloody sputum
> - Symptoms of other consequences of lung overexpansion such as pneumothorax, subcutaneous or mediastinal emphysema may also be present.

Such bubbles of gas can block circulation on the brain and cause a quick death sometimes. Unless the dragon is also an undead abomination, he wouldn't stand a chance against a bubble ninja wizard.

Answer (score 4):

## Distraction, visual impairment, breathing hazard

Bubbles are transparent, or so they seem. Put enough of them together, and they visually become opaque. A screen of tiny bubbles can hide a lot. Deployed correctly, they increase the survivability of the group. It is difficult to hit something you can not see.

Going through a wall of bubbles can also lead to surprisingly annoying effects. As the first bubbles wet the surface, there is a good chance many bubbles stick to the dragons surface. At a glance it might not seem that bad, but it might be hard to detect a person clinging to the scales if there are too many bubbles vying for attention. They can (very temporarily) blind the dragon, causing them to blink away the bubbly remains, adding a different layer of distraction and visual impairment.

As McTroopers mentions, bubbles aren't nice to breathe. Even in the case that bubbles are powerless against flame, the bubbles will likely trigger a reflex like most animals have when something goes into the wrong throat. Coughing, but for a dragon this might be a cough with flame. This reaction is decidedly not to kill people, so the flame is unlikely to be directed or particularly dangerous. At least compared to it's normal attack. This again gives valuable time to act in a more safe environment.

The bubbles can be another source of distraction, if the dragon isn't very intelligent. Huge bubbles can cause light refractions or weird mirror effects. This can make it difficult to aim, like spear fishers learn, but it can also scare or antagonise the dragon, as it sees a big dragon in attack mode in the reflections.

As with many things, power over even innocent things can be incredibly powerful. Using creativity and weaknesses you can make this pretty powerful. You can balance this with the time and effort invested to create bubbles, or having a finite resource. Yet all in all bubbles can be a great boon to the team.

Answer (score 2):

### Bubbles distract. Kites and thunder spell deadly weapon.

You should reconsider the roles of the members of your party a little: the Thunder Twin brother flies kites with conductive wiring while the adventurers wait for the Thunder Twin sister to attract a potent thunder storm.
All the while, as Bubbles deftly performs his bullamancy, the fearsome dragon can't help but wonder what these weird transparent spheres are, and how it's possible they contain tiny versions of themself. A fireball here and there is not enough to hold the fire-resistant dragon's attention for very long, after all.
Once a thunderstorm has been "conjured", the athletic Waterboy wraps himself in a protective, soothing layer of humidity, cooled on-the-fly by the Cool Kid, and storms off to the distracted dragon with a kite or two, nimbly mounts the beast, and attaches them near the weak points.

If being hit by lightning happens to only stun the dragon, your party's leader can still get his fireball in as a death blow.

What follows is a phantasmagoria of the elements, ending with the death of the evil dragon.

Answer (score 2):

Even if you restrict it to blowing bubbles (not permitting the offensive bubble creation Trish talks about) they have a very useful defensive capability if they can stand up to the dragon.  Dragon flame hits a bubble and is deflected.  Dragon claws can't grasp a bubble if it's too big.  An inconvenience but a considerable one.  Not to mention that the dragon is going to have a hard time hitting what it can't see--a stream of bubbles heading for it's eyes won't do any harm but will render it pretty much useless.

Answer (score 1):

### Void bubbles AKA cavitation

Quoting [wikipédia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cavitation) :

> Cavitation in fluid mechanics and engineering normally refers to the phenomenon in which the static pressure of a liquid reduces to below the liquid's vapour pressure, leading to the formation of small vapor-filled cavities in the liquid. When subjected to higher pressure, these cavities, called "bubbles" or "voids", collapse and can generate shock waves that may damage machinery.

Cavitation can litterally eat metal on the long term (see picture below) so imagine what could happen to a dragon if Bubbleboy is abble to instantly generates trillions of these microscopic "bombs" against its blood vessels walls and make them implose all in once ?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Well, bubbles are slippery when they hit the floor, and the detergent in them makes your eyes sore if they pop near the face.. combining these two superpowers, Bubbles can draw the attention of the dragon by screaming and waving while running towards a cliff, then at the last minute blow bubbles towards the eyes of the dragon, while coating the floor with more bubbles, thereby blinding it... everyone knows dragon's aren't very nimble, so it'll only realize the deceit too late, as inertia and the slippery floor slides it away into the abyss.

Answer (score 0):

**Mega energy exploding floating bubbles!**

Have you seen videos of the Hindenburg disaster?
That's what you get with Hydrogen and SOME air.
Get the mix 'right' and they'd all have been dead instantly :-(.

Have you ever seen a photo of the remains of a gas explosion :-(.

Almost any flammable gas mixed with air or oxygen in the correct (stoichiometric) ration and they will explode or give a very good imitation thereof. All such mixtures except one will be heavier than air due to the air or other gases in the mixture. A perfect Oxygen + Hydrogen mix weighs about 60% of the weight of the equivalent volume of air - SO a low mass bubble (thin and/or low density membrane) will float in air with a very explosive Oxygen + Hydrogen mix inside.

My quick "back of envelope" calculation suggests that a cubic metre of this gas weighs 800g or which 11% is Hydrogen. Hydrogen perfectly combusted delivers about 40,000 Watt hours of energy so 88g delivers about 3500 Watt hours or about 12+ MJ.  That's about 12 hand grenades. Add flammable sticky stuff as desired.

A large slightly less than neutral density bubble, or lots and lots of them, wafting towards a flaming dragon, each delivering impact shock of a hand grenade explosion or few, has a good chance of un-making its day.

E&OE - someone may wish to check my figures :-)

Answer (score 0):

### Bubble-wrap a wing and watch aerodynamic anarchy ensue

It is well known that the boundary layer of airflow over a wing can be disturbed quite greatly by small surface irregularities (particularly sensitive wings are [known to have issues with bug splatters](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/a/16956/3825)), diminishing the wing's ability to produce lift.  This is especially true when the demands on the wing are at their highest.

Furthermore, if they only affect *one* wing this way, they can create conditions that are ripe for the combination of stall and yaw that produces the dreaded aerodynamic spin, while practically being able to "lock" their target in that spin by making that affected wing unable to produce lift at *any* angle of attack.

As a result, provided your bubble-mage can keep their bubbles stuck to a surface, they can become an utterly insidious anti-air unit, knocking everything from dragons to drones out of the sky.  They just need to make sure they aren't doing this over population centers, lest they leave a dragon-sized crater in the middle of the city!

Answer (score 0):

**Fire Fighting Foam**

[image]

His ability negates the dragon's fire breath plus he can throw up walls of foam they can hide in or behind.